# When creating a chatServer that sends data using ObjectInput/OutputStreams I get a java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Good day
This is my first post, because I have no idea what to do :(

I am creating a web application that has 2 functions

1. It is a Tic Tac Toe multiplayer game.
2. It is a multiuser chat client.

So after many hours of hard work I got the multiuser chat to work (YAY!!). But the server/client was using strings to send data via PrintWriter and BufferedReader. Now that is all good, but I need (Specs say so) to send XML data through the server for the multiplayer game.

The problem comes in when I change all my PrintWriters and BufferedReaders to ObjectInputStreams and ObjectOutputStreams. I will give code to show where everything takes place.

This is the server's skeleton, which basically creates the ServerSocket then accepts all incoming connections which creates a new ChatHandler Object:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
//import javagently.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChatServer {

  /* The Chatter program    by J M Bishop  January 1997
   * ===================    Java 1.1 January 1998
   *                        updated August 2000
   *
   * Sets up a server for multiple conversations.
   *
   * Join in by typing
   * telnet x y
   * where x and y are the computer's name and port as
   * given when the Chatter starts.
   *
   * Illustrates sockets, streams on sockets,
   * threads, synchronization and the use of lists (again).
   */

  private static LinkedList clientList = new LinkedList();
  private static LinkedList clientListNames = new LinkedList();
  private static int id = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Get the port and created a socket there.
    int port = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the port"));
    if (args.length > 0)
      port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    new ChatServer (port);

  }


  class Terminal extends Thread{
      public Terminal(){      

      }
      public void run() {
          while(true){
              String message = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter command");
              if(message.equals("xxx")){
                  printClients();
              }
              if(message.equals("quit")){
                 System.exit(0);
              }

          }
      }
  }

  ChatServer (int port) throws IOException {
    //new Terminal().start();
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("The Chat Server is running on port "+port);

    // Listen for clients. Start a new handler for each.
    // Add each client to the linked list.
    while (true) {
      Socket client = listener.accept();
      new ChatHandler(client).start();
      System.out.println("New client no."+id+
          " from "+ listener.getInetAddress()+
          " on client's port "+client.getPort());
      clientList.add(client);      
      id++;
    }
  }

  synchronized static void broadcast(String message, String name, String type)
      throws IOException {
    // Sends the message to every client including the sender.
    Socket s;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;          

    for (ListIterator list = clientList.listIterator(); list.hasNext();) {
      s = (Socket) list.next();
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
      oos.writeChars(type+"#"+name+": "+message);
    }
  }

  synchronized static void sendToPeer(Object message, String name, String type, Socket receiver)
      throws IOException {
    // Sends the message to every client including the sender.
    Socket s = receiver;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;          
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    oos.writeChars(type+"#"+name+":"+message);

  }
synchronized static Socket getClient(String name){
    int pos = clientListNames.indexOf(name);
    return (Socket)clientList.get(pos);
}

  synchronized static void remove(Socket s, String n) {
  /* Using the LinkedList remove method, removes the
   * first occurrence of the given socket object
   */
    clientList.remove(s);
    clientListNames.remove(n);
    id--;
  }
  public static void printClients(){
      System.out.println("Printing Clients");
      for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println("Client: No"+i);
      }
  }
  public static String getClientNames() {
        String names = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < clientListNames.size(); i++) {
            names = names + "@" + clientListNames.get(i)+"@";
        }

      return names;
  }
  public static void addClientName(String cName){
      clientListNames.add(cName);
  }
}
```

This is the ChatHandler class, this is where I am getting my error:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Calendar;

class ChatHandler extends Thread {

  /* The Chat Handler class is called from the Chat Server:
   * one thread for each client coming in to chat.
   */

  private ObjectInputStream in;
  private ObjectOutputStream out;
  private Socket toClient;
  private String name;
  private boolean inGame= false;
  private Socket enemy;
  private String enemyName;

  ChatHandler(Socket s) {
    toClient = s;
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      /* Create i-o streams through the socket we were
       * given when the thread was instantiated
       * and welcome the new client.
       */

      in = new ObjectInputStream(toClient.getInputStream());
      out = new ObjectOutputStream(toClient.getOutputStream());
      //out.println("*** Welcome to the Chatter ***");
      //out.println("Type BYE to end");
      //out.println("What is your name? ");
      out.flush();
      String name = (String) in.readObject();
      ChatServer.addClientName(name);
      ChatServer.broadcast(name+" has joined the chat room.", "Server ("+getTime()+")","SHOW");
      String cNames = ChatServer.getClientNames();
      ChatServer.broadcast(cNames,"LISTCLIENTS","NOTSHOW");

      // Read lines and send them off for broadcasting.
      while (true) {
        Object o = in.readObject();
        if(o instanceof String){
            String s = (String) o;
            if (s.equals("BYE")) {
              ChatServer.broadcast(name+" has left the discussion.","Server ("+getTime()+")","SHOW");
              ChatServer.remove(toClient,name);
              toClient.close(); 
              cNames = ChatServer.getClientNames();
              ChatServer.broadcast(cNames,"LISTCLIENTS","NOTSHOW");
              return;
            }
            if(s.equals("LISTCLIENTS")){
                cNames = ChatServer.getClientNames();
                ChatServer.broadcast(cNames,"LISTCLIENTS","NOTSHOW");           
                ChatServer.broadcast(cNames,"LISTCLIENTS","SHOW");

            }if(s.contains("PLAYGAME")){ 
                enemyName = s.substring("PLAYGAME".length());
                if(!name.equals(enemyName)){
                    enemy = ChatServer.getClient(enemyName);
                    inGame = true;
                    String xml = createBoard(name, enemyName);
                    ChatServer.sendToPeer(xml, name, "PLAYWITHME", enemy);
                }            

            }else{
                cNames = ChatServer.getClientNames();
                ChatServer.broadcast(cNames,"LISTCLIENTS","NOTSHOW");
                ChatServer.broadcast(s, name + "("+getTime()+")","SHOW");
            }
        }

      }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Chatter error: "+e.getMessage());
  }
  }
  private String getTime(){
      int hours = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getHours();
      String strHours;
      if(hours<10){
          strHours = "0"+hours;
      }else{
          strHours = ""+hours;
      }
      int minutes = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getMinutes();
      String strMinutes;
      if(minutes<10){
          strMinutes = "0"+minutes;
      }else{
          strMinutes = ""+minutes;
      }

      int seconds = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getSeconds();
      String strSeconds;
      if(seconds<10){
          strSeconds = "0"+seconds;
      }else{
          strSeconds = ""+seconds;
      }

      return  strHours + ":" + strMinutes + ":" + strSeconds;
  }

    private String createBoard(String n, String en) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

I connect to the Java server through javascript with the help of this neat little applet: [Here](http://stephengware.com/proj/javasocketbridge/)

I am getting a 
"Chatter error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 46616269" 
when I reach the line : 
"in = new ObjectInputStream(toClient.getInputStream());"
 in the ChatHandler class

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Okay so I commented out the line "in = new ObjectInputStream(toClient.getInputStream());" and it seems to not crash when I create the out stream, so it is crashing on that line. I still have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: I also have edited the Javascript socket bridge so it works with ObjectStreams so it isnt a issue of mismatching the types